# HDMI -> DisplayPort / DVI adapter cable - does it work?

Tags: 12.04, hdmi, displayport

The computer I'm buying only has HDMI. My display has DVI and Displayport.

Will I be able to hook them up using an "HDMI to Displayport" converter cable in Ubuntu 12.04?

The videocard is IntelHD 4000.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDMI to DVI works like a charm. (cheap ones too)

Already tried it on many devices.

You'll have the video part of the hdmi converted without trouble. No quality loss.

Don't know about hdmi to display port. This one may cost higher.

Best regards.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll test it soon and I'll post results with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes they work.

If you wanted a for sure answer, you would need to find a person that already tried it with your specific video (which you listed) and your specific monitor (which is omitted).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no they don't.  DVI doesn't do audio and passive adapter cables absolutely will not take HDMI out to DisplayPort in.  The only device I can find that claims the ability is the Startech HDMI2DP active converter.  I won't know for sure until my Dell u3014 arrives.  It is available for around $80 at Amazon, BestBuy or Newegg and the reviews are mixed so if you try it be sure to pick a vendor with an easy return policy (and please report back here with your results.)

Answer (score 0):

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my laptop. I bought [this](http://a.co/fPvHrzO) cable from AmazonBasics. It is not working for me. I used the same cable on a separate Windows 10 desktop computer with the same monitor and it worked for me. Then I used a HDMI-to-VGA adapter and connected to the exact same monitor through a VGA cable without any problem.